# The case isn't shuting down

Tags: windows-10

It's been about a week that I clicked on the shut down button. The monitor is off but the case is not shutting down and sometimes it is getting stuck on the shut down screen and the monitor doesn't turn off either! Also my disk usage is always more than 97%. What should I do with this terrible problem?

[image]

I am using windows10 enterprise 64-bit and an Asus motherboared.

Comment: The case? The laptop case? the desktop case? Motherboard fully down and only some fans on a desktop case on? ... ?

Comment: Do you really have one week to wait for it to shut down?  It can even be a temporary issue.  First try to restart it, if that doesn't work keep the power button pressed for a few seconds until your pc stops.

Comment: What is the process using all the memory in the picture you provided?

Comment: If you are only going to down vote questions, at least provide the decency of giving us more information about your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Disk usage has never caused an error in shutting down as far as I know; your best bet is to simply unplug the computer after saving all your work. This will obviously force the device to shut down without power. Later after you have powered back up you can see if the problem persists, if so then check which programs you have running in the background.

The most common usage of 100 disk use that I have encountered is antivirus scans running through my hard drives. By default my antivirus software packages run these scans once a week, if for whatever reason your previous antivirus scan was not completed by the time a week was up and started another scan this could be one of several possible issues. Get back to us and let us know what the issue is.

Alternatively to unplugging your device, you can simply force a hard reboot by holding down the on/off button on your laptop or desktop computer. This will force the computer to shut down somewhat more gently than a loss of power would ensue.